# How cordova-plugin-file-downloader plugin in ionic project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have got a Cordova plugin from [here](https://github.com/mramonlopez/cordova-plugin-file-downloader), which can download the file from server write it in local storage, but how can I use this plugin in my ionic project after I have installed it?

Comment: You didn't see [docs usage](https://github.com/mramonlopez/cordova-plugin-file-downloader#usage) ?

Comment: I have seen it but how to import downloader in the ionic project? 
Eg: import { Zip } from '@ionic-native/zip'; here I imported zip.

Comment: It's automatically available after you install it by CLI => do `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-downloader`

Comment: How can you use it? @NelsonGnanaraj

Comment: I tried this `declare let downloader: any;`. This is working fine

Comment: Please refer here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-cordova-custom-plugin-in-ionic/123858/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the any installed cordova plugin by following way

```
declare let downloader: any;
```

Here you can refer to declare the cordova plugin https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-cordova-custom-plugin-in-ionic/123858